# jQuery focus() - why is it adding invisible elements?

Tags: jquery, focus, append

I have an interesting problem (to me at least).

I have a textarea which has an onfocus function to expand the textarea and append a cancel and submit button, here is the code:

```
$('.box').focus(function() {
                $(this).attr("status", "open");
                $(this).attr("rows", 5);
                $(this).parent().append("<button type='submit'>Submit</button><span class='cancel_comment' onclick='cancel_comment();'>Cancel</span>");
                $('#comment_container').css("height", ($('#right_display').innerHeight() - $('#description_container').outerHeight() - 15));
            });
```

The cancel button does the following (it puts it back to original look and format):

```
function cancel_comment(){
                $(this).attr("status", "closed");
                $('.box').attr("rows", 1);
                $('.cancel_comment').remove();
                $('#description_container button').remove();

            }
```

Both functions work perfectly on the first "click" or focus, but I noticed two things:

1. After I click cancel and run the cancel_comment() function, when I "click" or focus on the textarea again, it expands which tells me the first code is being implemented, however...
2. It adds the cancel and submit buttons boxas invisible (dimensionless) elements to the html (so if I click 5 times I have 1 visible set of buttons and 4 invisible sets of buttons in the html).

Any idea as to why this is?

---

Thanks for the comments!

Here is a jsfiddle which does NOT replicate the issue, it actually works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/livvyjeffs/8HZLX/7/

I've played around with where I am putting the jquery script code, for now I'm just putting it in  at the end of the body. **I am keeping it in the html document for ease and because I don't really know how to create a jQuery document - could this be causing it?** I know jQuery is finnicky about ordering.

Is there anything else that could cause this? I am thinking and looking through my code, will update with updates!

Comment: can you share the html sample also

Comment: if possible edit this fiddle to recreate the problem http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VMbqE/1/

Comment: One problem I see is that you can get multiple `focus` events even though you never hit the Cancel button (just switch focus to anything else, then back to the textarea).  You should probably only add the new buttons if they aren't already present.

Comment: `this` inside the `cancel_comment` does not refer the textarea